# f.state is not a function wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm new on wordpress , i don't know how to fix this error.

When I go to “costumize” I can’t see the options that I need to change the header, the layout, colour, blog options, widget options… that normally are in the left column.

and the console show this error

> f.state is not a function"

[image: error]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not wordpress error, try to change your theme and see if error persist or not.